# Proper and cocompact group action by isometries on a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

I am reading the book "Metric spaces of Non-Positive Curvature" by Bridson and Haefilger and got stuck with the following :

> **Proposition II.6.10(2)** Let $\Gamma$ be a group that acts properly by isometries on a metric space $X$. If the action is cocompact then every element of $\Gamma$ is semi simple.

[image: page 233]
In the proof I couldn't understand the highlighted line

---

According to the book a group action is ***proper*** if for every $x\in X$ there exist $r>0$ such that the set $\{\gamma\in \Gamma|\gamma B(x,r)\cap B(x,r)\not=\phi\}$ is finite.(section II.8.2)

And an action is ***cocompact*** if there exists a compact set $K$ such that $X=\Gamma K$.(section II.8.1)

I have spent a lot of time trying to justify this argument. Although I was able to find justification for this assuming $X$ is a proper metric space , but couldn't do it for general case .

Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: @User I have already seen it and there they say nothing about II.6.10(2) . They are concerned about II.6.10(3).

Comment: I am quite sure they forgot to assume properness of the space for this part. But I do not have a counter-example at the moment. Assuming properness of $X$, the proof of semisimplicity is not hard.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I agree with you . I have emailed Martin R. Bridson regarding this but didn't got a reply.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't think so: properness of the space is even a consequence of the assumptions. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any missing assumption. Indeed cocompactness is enough to take advantage of compactness.

Let me also clarify the properness assumption. A action of a discrete group on a metric space is topologically proper (resp. metrically proper) if for every compact (resp. bounded) subset $K$, the set of $g\in G$ such that $K\cap gK$ is finite. "Metrically proper" implies "topologically proper", and the book uses "proper" to mean "metrically proper".

The definition of proper in the Bridson-Haefliger book should be taken as "metrically proper". (Their definition is flawed and should not be used as the given result fails otherwise, see the comments.)

Write $h_n=\gamma_n\gamma\gamma_n^{-1}$. They justify that $d(h_ny_n,y_n)$ is bounded. It follows that $d(h_nx,x)$ is bounded for every $x$ (namely by $2\sup_n d(x,y_n)$, which is bounded since $y_n\in K$). Metric properness of the action precisely means that every sequence $(h_n)$ such that $d(h_nx,x)$ is bounded for some $x$, is bounded (i.e., lies in one finite subset).

---

Not only properness of the space is not a missing assumption, but it is a consequence of the assumptions.

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a metric space with a cocompact metrically proper action of a discrete group $G$. Then $X$ is a proper metric space.

[The action is not supposed isometric, not even continuous. For an isometric action properness is equivalent to $d(gx,x)\to\infty$ when $g\in\infty$, for some $x\in X$ and hence every $x$.]

Proof. Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $X$. Write $x_n=g_nk_n$ with $g_n\in G$, $k_n\in K$. By metric properness of the action, $g_n$ remains in a finite subset. So, after extracting, we can suppose $g_n$ constant, say $g_n=g$, so $x_n=gk_n$. Hence for any limit point $k$ of $(k_n)$, $gk$ is a limit point.

Comment: If I am not missing anything, then your definition and their definitions are different. Here are some lines from the book (pages $131-132$):

Comment: $8.2$ **Definition of a Proper Action.** Let $\Gamma$ be a group acting by isometries on a metric space $X$. The action is said to be proper (alternatively, "$\Gamma$ acts properly on $X$") if for each $x\in X$ there exists a number $r > 0$ such that the set $\big\{\gamma\in \Gamma\big|y\cdot B(x, r) \cap B(x, r) \neq\varnothing \big\}$ is finite.

Comment: $8.3$ Remarks

$(1)$ It is more usual to define an action of a group $\Gamma$ on a topological space $X$ to be proper if for every compact subset $K\subset X$ the set of elements $\{\gamma\in \Gamma | \gamma\cdot K\cap K\neq \varnothing\}$ is finite. *The definition that we have adopted is equivalent to the standard definition in the case of actions by groups of isometries on proper metric spaces, but in general, it is more restrictive.* ........

Comment: @User you're right, one really needs metric properness, as used in the book. I've fixed the answer. (I called "topologically proper" the "more usual" definition of properness, which is not enough for the conclusion. Indeed for infinite $G$, the left action on itself with the $\{0,1\}$ valued metric is isometric, proper and cocompact but this is not a proper space. If instead one chooses a metric valued in $[1,2]$ such that for some $g$ with infinite conjugacy class, $\{d(hgh^{-1},1):h\in G\}$ has no minimum, one also sees the failure of (2) assuming only topological properness.

Comment: @YCor: I am confused, it does not seem that the answer was fixed. As for a counter-example where the minimum is not attained, could you write down details?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why do you say it's not fixed? I modified the answer adding definition of metrically/topologically proper action, and adding "metrically" in the lemma.

Comment: @YCor: But your definition is not the same as the one in BH: In their definition of metric properness they use the existential quantifier, not the universal one.

Comment: @MoisheKohan indeed the definition as quoted is absurd, since it makes the action of $G$ on itself with distance $\{0,1\}$ proper. Such a definition, if correctly quoted, should be taken as a misprint.

Comment: @MoisheKohan As regards the counterexample to (2). Choose a group $G$ with an infinite conjugacy class $C$. Choose an arbitrary function $L:G\to \{0\}\cup [1,2]$ with the only requirements: $L(1)=0$, $L(g)=L(g^{-1})$ for all $g$, $L(g)\in [1,2]$ for $g\neq 1$, and $L(C)$ has no minimum. Define the left-invariant distance $d(g,h)=L(g^{-1}h)$. Then for $g\in C$, $|g|$ is not attained. This action is not metrically proper, but topologically proper. It is also "absurd-proper", where absurd-proper is the definition as written in the above comment by User.

Comment: @YCor: I understood the example, could you modify your answer to make it clear that their result in (2) is incorrect as written? (Not everybody interested in the question will read the comments.) I do not like their definition of properness of an action either, but (unfortunately) it is  similar to the one used by many topologists, so I am not sure it was a misprint. (Many topologists would say that a properly discontinuous  action of a group $G$ on a space $X$ is one where for every $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $gU\cap U\ne \emptyset\Rightarrow g=1$.)

Comment: Just as a reference, [page 131](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Metric_Spaces_of_Non_Positive_Curvature/M7XrCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=group+actions+and+quasi+isometries+Metric+SpacesofNon-Positive+Curvature&pg=PA131&printsec=frontcover) and [page 132](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Metric_Spaces_of_Non_Positive_Curvature/M7XrCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=group+actions+and+quasi+isometries+Metric+SpacesofNon-Positive+Curvature&pg=PA132&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thanks everyone for this prolonged discussion. I appreciate your help.